# Can I get the ID of a related object without accessing the database in Django

Tags: django

If I have a instance of an object, can I get the ID of a related object without needing to access the database? The value must be storred somewhere.

eg

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
book.author.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django automatically creates a field for the id of the object by using the field name and suffixing it with _id eg:

```
book.author_id == book.author.id
```

It's not very well documented in django's docs but two blog posts on the matter for reference:

http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/django-orm-performance-tips-part-2/
http://thebuild.com/blog/2010/12/22/getting-the-id-of-related-objects-in-django/